# Passing Jquery Function from Node via HTTP response

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, http-get

I am working with a Node (Express) based API, which, upon request, passes some HTML and jQuery to the frontend, which is embedded into the document.  I'm looking for a neat way to stringify the function on the backend so that I can send it to the frontend.  I'm trying to minimize the amount of code that I have to put on the frontend.  This is what I have now, which is functional, but feels a little ugly and is hard to debug.

```
   responseData.scripts = "<script>";
var search_request =
    "$('#search_form').submit(function(event) { "+
            "event.preventDefault();"+
        "data.stage = 'search';"+
        "data.query.first_name='Bob';"+   

        "$.ajax({"+
                "type: 'GET',"+
                "url: 'http://159.203.131.150:3000',"+
            "data:data,"+
            "crossDomain: true,"+
            "success: function(response) {"+
                "response = JSON.parse(response);"+
                "console.log(response);"+
            "}"+            
        "})" +
    "})" +
 "</script>";
 responseData.scripts+=search_request;
```

On the front-end, I have

```
  $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://159.203.131.150:3000",
 data: data,
 crossDomain: true,   

 success: function(response) {
   response = JSON.parse(response);
   $(response.html).prependTo("#content");
   $(response.scripts).appendTo("body");
 },   


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://159.203.131.150:3000",
 data: data,
 crossDomain: true,   

 success: function(response) {
   response = JSON.parse(response);
   $(response.html).prependTo("#content");
   $(function () {
      $('<script>')
        .attr('type', 'text/javascript')
        .text(response.scripts)
        .appendTo('body');
   })
 }   
});
```

and remove the script tag from the server side response

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep.  This isn't quite what I was asking about.  I'm not having any trouble on the client side, actually things are working the way I have it written.  I'm looking for an neater alternative to the method I'm using on the server side to stringify the the jQuery to send to the client-side

Comment: Is there a reason to do thing on the client side the way you recommend vs. what I have?

Answer (score 0):

I found an Express function to do this (I'm new to Express, it's a pretty basic function).  I ended up storing the javascript file in a public folder and serving it from my app.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html